# Asymptotics of sum of binomial distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random

**Definition 1:** For any random variable $X$, we define $\mathrm{Bin}(p,X)$ as a variable with binomial distribution having parameters $p$ and $X$.

**Definition 2:** For all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, define recursively the following random variables, $$X_{i+1} = \mathrm{Bin}(p, X_{i}^1) + \mathrm{Bin}(1-p, X_{i}^2),$$ where
the two random variables "$\mathrm{Bin}$" in the sum are independent for every $i\in \mathbb{N}$ and where $X_{i}^1$ and $X_{i}^2$ are independent and distributed the same as $X_i$. The initial random variable $X_0$ is given and it has expectation $\lambda>0$.

**Question 1:** Is the probability distribution of $X_\infty$ well defined and unique?

**Question 2:** If yes, does the probability distribution of $X_\infty$ solve the following equation, $X_\infty = \mathrm{Bin}(p, X_{\infty}^1) + \mathrm{Bin}(1-p, X_{\infty}^2)$, where $X_\infty^1$ and $X_\infty^2$ have the same probability distribution of $X_\infty$ and the variables in the sum are independent? Clearly for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]=\lambda$.

This question is related to my other question, [Solution of equation of binomial random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706814/solution-of-equation-of-binomial-random-variables), where the equation $X = \mathrm{Bin}(p, X^1) + \mathrm{Bin}(1-p, X^2)$ has been solved, under the assumption that $X$, $X^1$ and $X^2$ are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: Do you know any martingale theory?

Comment: I initially wrote an answer, but I just noticed that you want $X_{i+1}=Bin(p,X_i^1) + Bin(1-p,X_i^2)$ rather than $X_{i+1}=Bin(p,X_i) + Bin(1-p,X_i)$. In the latter case, $X_i\rightarrow 0$

Comment: "under the assumption that $X$, $X^1$ and $X^2$ are independent and identically distributed" No, under the assumption that $X$, $X^1$ and $X^2$ are identically distributed and that $X^1$ and $X^2$ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, this is really the iteration of a transformation of *distributions*, not random variables, and the technique used to find the fixed points in the other question can be adapted to solve the asymptotics.

To be brief (since this is a rehashing of arguments already explained), the sequence of generating functions $\varphi_n(s)=E(s^{X_n})$ solves the recursion $$\varphi_{n+1}(s)=\varphi_n(p+qs)\varphi_n(q+ps)=\varphi_n(1-q(1-s))\varphi_n(1-p(1-s)),$$ where $q=1-p$, hence $$\log\varphi_n(s)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\log\varphi_0(1-p^kq^{n-k}(1-s)).
$$
Assuming that $X_0$ is square integrable with $E(X_0)=\lambda$, one knows that, when $t\to0$, $$\varphi_0(1-t)=1-\lambda t+O(t^2),$$ hence, for some suitable $A$ and $B$, $$-\lambda t+At^2\leqslant\log\varphi_0(1-t)\leqslant-\lambda t+Bt^2,$$ for every $t$. Thus, on the one hand,
$$\log\varphi_n(s)\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left(-\lambda p^kq^{n-k}(1-s)+Bp^{2k}q^{2(n-k)}(1-s)^2\right),$$ that is, $$\log\varphi_n(s)\leqslant-\lambda(1-s)+B\cdot(p^2+q^2)^n(1-s)^2.
$$
On the other hand, $$\log\varphi_n(s)\geqslant-\lambda(1-s)+A\cdot(p^2+q^2)^n(1-s)^2.
$$
Since $p^2+q^2\lt1$, this shows that $\log\varphi_n(s)\to-\lambda(1-s)$ for every $s$, that is, that the distributions converge to the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=E(X_0)$.

To sum up:

> **Question 1:** Is the probability distribution of $X_\infty$ well defined and unique?

Yes.

> **Question 2:** If yes, does the probability distribution of $X_\infty$ solve the following equation, $X_\infty = \mathrm{Bin}(p, X_{\infty}^1) + \mathrm{Bin}(1-p, X_{\infty}^2)$, where $X_\infty^1$ and $X_\infty^2$ have the same probability distribution [as] $X_\infty$ and the variables in the sum are independent?

Yes.